# Is there a way to input in the "output" channel of Visual Studio Code (specifically Python)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm a beginner to Python and I'm trying to use Visual Studio Code to build some of my programs.  Does VSC allow user input?  When I run something like

```
text=input()
```

It won't let me input anything in the output channel.  It says "Cannot edit in read-only editor."  Anything I should do?

Comment: Output channel is for output, not input. It should be obvious from the name of it. If you want to give input, use integrated terminal instead

Comment: What is this for?

Comment: @KarlOlufsen I figured that was the wrong way to go about it but I didn't know the right way, so I made this silly post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Debug Console" on VSCode is not an input stream. It is just for output and evaluation, so you need to config VSCode to run your code in the real terminal.

In the `.vscode/luanch.json` file, you need to define `integratedTerminal` as your `console`.

Also, make sure your program is really running and not failed just after you launched it.

Please read the documentation [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_initialize-configurations)